# Can't create compound indexes using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query

I tried all the suggestions i could find but still can't figure the problem:

```
var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Param1:      String,
    Param2:      String,
    Param3:      Number
})

testSchema.index = ({Param1: 1, Param2: 1} , { unique: true })


var Test= mongoose.model("Test", testSchema)
```

I have deleted my collections and databases but can only manage to create the index by manually adding to the db.
The code can read and write from the db but no index is created.
How can i troubleshoot this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`model.index` is a function.

```js
testSchema.index({ Param1: 1, Param2: 1 } , { unique: true });
```